# posts archive page - closing WP_Query loop correctly

Tags: wp-query, loop

I am trying to use an example of the loop shown in this post [Output yearly archive within a page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144570/output-yearly-archive-within-a-page)
to output post links grouped by year

[image]

**page-archive.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template for displaying archive page
 **/

get_header();
?>

    <main id="primary" class="page-archive">


  <h1>Archive</h1>

  <?php 
// https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144570/output-yearly-archive-within-a-page
$posts = new WP_Query (
  array (
    'post_type'=>'post', 
    'post_status'=>'publish', 
    'posts_per_page'=>-1
    )
  ); 
 
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
 

 
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post(); 
          $year = get_the_time('Y');

           if ($posts->current_post === 0) 

           printf( '<h3>%s</h3>', $year ); 
           
          elseif ($last_year !== $year)
           printf( '<h3>%s</h3>', $year );
      

    ?>       
          <div>
                
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>
                <div><?php the_time( 'j F Y' ) ?></div>
            </div>


    <?php
            if ( ( $posts->current_post + 1 ) === $posts->post_count ) echo '</li>'; // Always close the <li> at the end of the loop
        $last_year = $year;

        endwhile;

    ?>


    <?php endif ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
 

    </main><!-- #main -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

**Question:**

in the following **if statement** if the condition is true the author echos **li**

```
if ( ( $posts->current_post + 1 ) === $posts->post_count )
            echo '</li>'; // Always close the <li> at the end of the loop
     $last_year = $year;
```

however, since I don't need to output anything and just want to close the loop when there's no more posts,  what would be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

delete the following line of code

```
if ( ( $posts->current_post + 1 ) === $posts->post_count )
        echo '</li>';
```

leaving only the following portion

```
 <?php
        
    $last_year = $year;

    endwhile;

?>
```